# Override protocol buffers default behavior of throwing NPE when setting null to fields

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I use protocol buffers maven plugin to compile `.proto` files. I really like protocol buffers except for one thing that it doesn't accepts nulls as default or no value. Instead it throws NPE whenever `null` is passed. Preventing this NPE unnecessarily bloats up the code, way too much & I seriously want to avoid this anyhow!

I've seen this request/issue been strongly proposed by community & rejected by PB team. Now I'm looking for any ways I could override this behavior by modifying/ implementing any of the classes myself so that my proto files are compiled to produce code which doesn't throw NPE on nulls. Can anyone suggest how to? 
Or is there any easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I'm looking for any ways I could override this behavior by modifying/ implementing any of the classes myself so that my proto files are compiled to produce code which doesn;t throw NPE on nulls.

Simply put, you'd want to change the message generator code. It's complicated, but it's not *that* complicated. The downside is that it's in C++... and of course you'd need to maintain your fork in the future, or be stuck with protobuf in its current form.

You probably want to start off by looking at [`java_string_field.cc`](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_string_field.cc) and [`java_message_field.cc`](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_message_field.cc).

I'd estimate that it's only a couple of days' work, if that - but you'd be taking on a small-but-present maintenance burden forever.

Of course, an alternative would be to rewrite the message generation yourself entirely from scratch - which is clearly a much bigger task, but one I eventually did for my [protobuf-csharp-port](http://protobuf-csharp-port.googlecode.com) project... after getting a C++ version working. (My port follows the same non-nullity approach though.)

Comment: huh ;) isn't there some easier way to do this ?

Comment: @user01: No, I don't think so. It's just not the way the generated code works, and changing the generator is going to be the easiest way of *making* it behave the way you want it to. Personally I'd prefer it to work that way too, but *at best* it would have to be an option, as changing it would change the behaviour of a heck of a lot of code. (You also need to consider whether all the primitive setters should take the wrapper types, to allow the field to be cleared by passing in null.)